# Sort a map on value attribute

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I'm trying to do a table with a map, and when I click on the header of a column, I want it to be sorted on this attribute

I've tried the keyValuePipe in Angular which is great and sort my map as I want it, my problem is when I change my sort value, the pipe is not triggered

Here is the ts code :

```
  orderByAttribute = (a,b) => {
    return a.value[this.sortType] > b.value[this.sortType] ? -1 : (a.value[this.sortType] < b.value[this.sortType] ? 1 : 0);
  };

  setAttribute(object) {
    this.sortType = object;
  }
```

and here is the HTML code :

```
<table class="table">
  <thead class="table--column-title">
    <tr>
      <th>
        HEADER 1
        <i class="material-icons"  (click)="setAttribute('value1')">arrow_drop_down</i>
      </th>
      <th>
        HEADER 2
        <i class="material-icons"  (click)="setAttribute('value2')">arrow_drop_down</i>
      </th>
      <th>
        HEADER 3
        <i class="material-icons"  (click)="setAttribute('value3')">arrow_drop_down</i>
      </th>
      <th>
        HEADER 4
        <i class="material-icons"  (click)="setAttribute('value4')">arrow_drop_down</i>
      </th>
      <th>
        HEADER 5
        <i class="material-icons"  (click)="setAttribute('value5')">arrow_drop_down</i>
      </th>
      <th>
        HEADER 6
        <i class="material-icons"  (click)="setAttribute('value6')">arrow_drop_down</i>
      </th>
      <th>
        HEADER 7
        <i class="material-icons" (click)="setAttribute('value7')" >arrow_drop_down</i>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="tr-row" *ngFor="let detail of data | keyvalue : orderByAttribute">
      <td class="td-cell">{{detail.value.value1}}</td>
      <td class="td-cell">{{detail.value.value2}}</td>
      <td class="td-cell">{{detail.value.value3}}</td>
      <td class="td-cell">{{detail.value.value4}}</td>
      <td class="td-cell">{{detail.value.value5}}</td>
      <td class="td-cell">{{detail.value.value6}}</td>
      <td class="td-cell">{{detail.value.value7}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

With my default sort value it work, but I didn't find a way to trigger the pipe on the ngFor to set my new sort value ... I've tried a ChangeDetectorRef and it doesn't work

I hope someone can help me !

have a nice day :)

EDIT : Stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2vrv9u !

Comment: Kindly provide a stackblitz for this

Comment: Stackblitz provided :) @MoxxiManagarm